# Open views content in new window?

Tags: views

Is there a way to open content in new window or add back button to it in views?

When you click on a content title from Views list there needs to be a quick way to navigate back to that list after viewing content.

Answer (score 1):

In views there is an option called Rewrite out put. You can use the rewrite out but as link and Provide the link as well as the target.

If everything is going through views then you can change the path of your content to reflect the path of your view using the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and use a breadcrumb module that would allow you to create breadcrumb from the path this way the path to the main view would be displayed in the breadcrumb for better navigation. You can take a look at the [breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/breadcrumb) module

Comment: won't let me mark up your answer but thanks :)

Comment: "The easiest and quickest method of outputting the views in the format that you want is using rewrite output option, It is easy and we can easily output the view in any format that we want without creating a single template file. The downside is it can just be used for theming row output and not the whole view. But I think this is good enough. You can create a single template file for the whole view and for the rest you can use rewrite output."